# Why can't I add a Component to a JFrame with a MouseListener?

Tags: java, swing

I have a `JFrame`. When I click in the frame, I want to add a `Component` (in this case an extension of a `Canvas`). I added a `MouseListener` to the frame as follows:

```
    frame.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            frame.add(canvas);
            frame.repaint();
        }
    });
```

However, the component is not added when the mouse is clicked on the frame. I have no problem adding the component in my main method. Adding a print statement in the mouse listener prints correctly, as does removing components from the frame.

Comment: what is the layout?`revalidate()` also required

Comment: try adding `frame.pack()` before your repaint.

Comment: Use a [`CardLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) as shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5786005/418556).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @sprinter9 said, add `frame.pack()` before repainting.
Try below

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

public class Frame {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Add Component");
        final Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
        canvas.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

        frame.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Clicked");
                frame.add(canvas);
                frame.pack();
                frame.repaint();
            }
        });


        frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(320,240));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Demo, http://kurungkurawal.com/gifs/frame-add-component.gif

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the component directly to the JFrame. You should use it's contentPane instead:

```
    frame.getContentPane().add(canvas);
```